# How to correctly specify nesting for lme formula

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

My data:

```
within factor:   Time - fixed
between factor:  Treatment - fixed
DV:              Nmin
Nesting:         Sample (random), nested in Postion (fixed), nested in Location (fixed).
```

Each treatment is applied to two of the locations.

My current formula is:

```
aov(Nmin~(Treatment*Location+Position)*Time) + 
    Error(sample/ ((Location+Position)*Time)), data)
lme(Nmin~Treatment*(Location+Position)*Time, random=~1|sample, Correlation=???)
```

My aim is to see for differences of `Nmin` between `Time`, `Treatment`, `Position`, `Location` and their interactions.

My question is, are my formulae correct?

- Is the nesting correctly expressed?
- Does this also take into consideration the interaction?
- Is the error term correct?